# Binding material-ui dropdown to table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to bind react material-ui dropdown to table? I have a drop down with countries and a table with country and capital city. Based on the selected country, table should show only that country and capital.
Below is my code.
First issue is, dropdownlist value is not updated correctly. Second issue is, table is not updated when the dropdownlist value changes.

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    country: "",
    rows: [
      createData("US", "DC"),
      createData("UK", "London"),
      createData("Aus", "Canberra")
    ]
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues(oldValues => ({
      ...oldValues,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
  }

  function createData(country, capital) {
    return { country, capital };
  }
  var rows = [
    createData("US", "DC"),
    createData("UK", "London"),
    createData("Aus", "Canberra")
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label value="Select Country: ">Select Country: </label>
      <Select
        style={{ width: "10%" }}
        value={values.country}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="country"
        displayEmpty
        className={classes.selectEmpty}>
        <MenuItem value="">Country</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>US</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>UK</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Aus</MenuItem>
      </Select>

      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center">Country</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">Capital city</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {values.rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.country}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.capital}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a few minor changes...

- Add `value` prop for `MenuItem`'s
- Add ability to filter using selected `MenuItem`'s value
- (This is personal preference) but I find it easier to separate state into their own objects - I believe this may also be recommended by React, but would have to look through the docs...

***Live Demo:***
[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938654/binding-material-ui-dropdown-to-table]

***Code:***

```
let API_DATA = [
  { country: "US", capital: "DC" },
  { country: "UK", capital: "London" },
  { country: "Aus", capital: "Canberra" }
];

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [tableData, setTableData] = React.useState(API_DATA);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
    let _vals = event.target.value
      ? API_DATA.filter(r => r.country === event.target.value)
      : API_DATA;
    setTableData(_vals);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label value="Select Country: ">Select Country: </label>
      <Select
        style={{ width: "30%" }}
        value={selected}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="country"
        displayEmpty
        className={classes.selectEmpty}
      >
        <MenuItem value="">All Countries</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="US">US</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="UK">UK</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="Aus">Aus</MenuItem>
      </Select>

      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center">Country</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">Capital city</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {tableData.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.country}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{row.capital}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```